# ASP.NET Retrieve Iphone Calendar Events

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, iphone, asp.net-mvc

I am basically trying to create a web application using ASP.NET MVC with the goal of syncing an iPhone's Calendar to the web application. What I am looking to do is have a sync button which the user will click on and the application will then import/export the calendars events. So for example a user has an event "Wifes Birthday" once the sync button is clicked the event and any times and dates will be fed into the web app. Is this even possible using ASP.NET?

Comment: Your iPhone doesn't care what server side software your site uses. It could be PHP, Java Server Pages, or ASP.NET and it won't matter to the iPhone. The iPhone just knows how to process files that your web server sends the iPhone. And [iCalendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) is the common format for calendar data.

Comment: So is there a way for a web app to request/make changes to the iPhone's calendar?

Comment: Make an iCalendar file. Have the phone download the file. See what happens.

Comment: @mason I suspect OP is looking for two-way sync (which probably means some sort of calendaring server supporting appropriate protocol - possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV). Just serving iCalendar files probably not be enough.

Comment: @Alexei you're probably right, but I just wanted to get him started and encourage a little research.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Correct, events going in and events going out. I researched this a bit using a native iPhone app using the EventKit feature. I'm not sure similar functionality can be achieved through a web app.

Comment: Did you see Alexei mentioning CalDav above? You need to do some research.

Comment: @prola in the end, what did you use then?